# Continuity requiremtent in the Heat Equation's Maximum principle

Tags: partial-differential-equations, maximum-principle

I have a short question regarding some inconsistency I've seen between the statement and actual usage of the maximum principle which I hope you could clarify for me.

> Theorem (The Maximum Principle):
>
> Let ${\Omega _T} = \left\{ {\left( {x,t} \right)|a \le x \le b,0 \le t \le T} \right\}$ and suppose $u(x,t)$ satisfies the heat equation in
>   the interior of ${\Omega _T}$ and is **continuous** on ${\Omega _T}$, then
>   the maximum of $u(x,t)$ in ${\Omega _T}$ is attained on the parabolic
>   boundary  $$P = \left\{ {\left( {x,t} \right)|x = a,0 \le t \le T} \right\} \cup \left\{ {\left( {x,t} \right)|x = b,0 \le t \le T} \right\} \cup \left\{ {\left( {x,t} \right)|a \le x \le b,t = 0} \right\}$$

The requirement that $u(x,t)$ is continuous is indeed used in the proof of this theorem as it used to argue, that by Weierstrass' theorem, the function $u(x,t)$ attains it maximum value on (the compact set) ${\Omega _T}$.

But I've seen numerous exercises where the above maximum principle was used in situations where $u(x,t)$ was clearly not continuous.

For example, in a situation like this
$$\left\{ \matrix{
  {u_t} = {u_{xx}}{\rm{                      ,         }}a < x < b,t > 0 \hfill \cr 
  u\left( {x,0} \right) = 1{\rm{                  ,        }}a \le x \le b \hfill \cr 
  u\left( {a,t} \right) = u\left( {b,t} \right) = 0{\rm{    ,        }}t \ge 0 \hfill \cr}  \right.$$

the maximum principle was used to conclude that $u\left( {x,t} \right) \le 1$ even though it's clear that $u(x,t)$ is not continuous at $(a,0)$ nor is it continuous at $(b,0)$.

So is there some generalization of the maximum principle that I am not aware of?

Thank you kindly in advance.

Comment: Just a small question / observation, referring to your example. The boundary / initial data seem to be incompatible; shouldn't you have $u(a, t) = u(b, t) = 0$ for $t > 0$? In this case, since the initial datum is smooth, the solution will also be smooth.

Comment: @bgsk You are right. But I think that even after that change the function u(x,t) wouldn't ve continuous on the boundary since the limit of u(x,0) when x approaches a+ is 1 while the limit of u(a,t) when t approaches 0+ is 0. Thus u(x,t) is discontinuous at (a,0).